# Install iOS12 simulator on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Im running Xcode 9.2, updating to Xcode 10 means a huge update to my codebase, not quite ready for that. I need to run a simulator with iOS 12 capabilities. Is this possible?

Comment: You won't be submitting the app to the AppStore unless you build it in Xcode 10, so it might be just as well to bite the bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of:

- Download Xcode 10 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10/Xcode_10.xip) (You can download it from Appstore but be sure to back up the Xcode 9 first and do not replace it)
- Run Xcode 9
- Build your project (command + B)
- Run Xcode 10 with new project
- Run iOS 12 simulator
- Open your project in any Xcode version you want
- Drag the project target file (myProject.app) into the simulator.
- Click on your app icon

[image]

This method prevents your codebase from those huge update.

Comment: i need to run the debugger unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for that. You can find the highest simulator version that Xcode supports from Xcode --> Preferences --> Components. But you can use instruments to debug your app without Xcode itself.